# How to select last rows of table group by category

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Here is my table.
[click here to see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3sRo.png)

I want to select last inserted rows uniquely `category`.

For example you see the table **breastfeeding** 3 times under the column `category`  so I want it only `last inserted` row. and **formula** has 2 Times but it also should return last inserted row.

write now I handle it by 11 times call this method so it's take too much time.

```
func getLast(category : String)-> [Activity]!{
        let query =  "SELECT *  FROM activitytb where category = \"\(category)\"  order by started desc limit 1"  
        return  execute(query)
    }
```

but it's not a good practice so I want it achieve by one query. I trying last few days to make it's one query but disparately failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to get the last inserted row for each category. You can do it using a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM activitytb
  ORDER BY started DESC
) s
GROUP BY s.category
```